How to call the drawing software that comes with Windows to convert a bmp image into a monochrome bitmap
How to call the drawing software that comes with Windows to convert a bmp image into a monochrome bitmap
Recently I was writing a label design software, but the bmp file I generated could never be printed using a label printer. Here is the code I use:
     private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
         panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height));

         //Bitmap bmpIndexed = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);


         bmp.Save("led1.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

         bmp.Dispose();
         //bmpIndexed.Dispose();
         ResizeBmp("led1.bmp");

         paint();
     }



     private void ResizeBmp(string path)
     {
         //Load images
         Image originalImage = Image.FromFile(path);

         // new size
         int newWidth = 192;
         int newHeight = 168;

         //Create a new Bitmap object to store the resized image
         Bitmap resizedImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

         //Create a Graphics object for manipulating images
         using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resizedImage))
         {
             //Set interpolation mode to preserve image quality
             g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

             // Draw the resized image
             g.DrawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
         }

         //// Convert the resized image to black and white
         //Bitmap monoImage = ConvertToMonochrome(resizedImage);
         // Save the resized image to a file


         ConvertTo1Bit(resizedImage).Save("led.bmp");

         // Release resources
         originalImage.Dispose();
         resizedImage.Dispose();
         //monoImage.Dispose();
         //newbitmap.Dispose();

         File.Delete("led1.bmp");
     }


     public static Bitmap ConvertTo1Bit(Bitmap input)
     {
         var masks = new byte[] { 0x80, 0x40, 0x20, 0x10, 0x08, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01 };
         var output = new Bitmap(input.Width, input.Height, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
         var data = new sbyte[input.Width, input.Height];
         var inputData = input.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, input.Width, input.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
         try
         {
             var scanLine = inputData.Scan0;
             var line = new byte[inputData.Stride];
             for (var y = 0; y < inputData.Height; y++, scanLine += inputData.Stride)
             {
                 Marshal.Copy(scanLine, line, 0, line.Length);
                 for (var x = 0; x < input.Width; x++)
                 {
                     data[x, y] = (sbyte)(64 * (GetGreyLevel(line[x * 3 + 2], line[x * 3 + 1], line[x * 3 + 0]) - 0.5));
                 }
             }
         }
         finally
         {
             input.UnlockBits(inputData);
         }
         var outputData = output.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, output.Width, output.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
         try
         {
             var scanLine = outputData.Scan0;
             for (var y = 0; y < outputData.Height; y++, scanLine += outputData.Stride)
             {
                 var line = new byte[outputData.Stride];
                 for (var x = 0; x < input.Width; x++)
                 {
                     var j = data[x, y] > 0;
                     if (j) line[x / 8] |= masks[x % 8];
                     var error = (sbyte)(data[x, y] - (j ? 32 : -32));
                     if (x < input.Width - 1) data[x + 1, y] += (sbyte)(7 * error / 16);
                     if (y < input.Height - 1)
                     {
                         if (x > 0) data[x - 1, y + 1] += (sbyte)(3 * error / 16);
                         data[x, y + 1] += (sbyte)(5 * error / 16);
                         if (x < input.Width - 1) data[x + 1, y + 1] += (sbyte)(1 * error / 16);
                     }
                 }
                 Marshal.Copy(line, 0, scanLine, outputData.Stride);
             }
         }
         finally
         {
             output.UnlockBits(outputData);
         }
         return output;
     }

     public static double GetGreyLevel(byte r, byte g, byte b)
     {
         return (r * 0.299 + g * 0.587 + b * 0.114) / 255;
     }

Yes, as the code shows, this label design software can only print monochrome bmp, so I converted the bmp image into a monochrome bmp, but this still doesn't work.
After two days of constant trying, I figured out where the problem was. I used the drawing software that comes with Windows, put bmp1 into it and saved it as a monochrome bitmap, and the picture was successfully printed.
So my focus here is to know how to directly call the drawing software that comes with Windows and save bmp as a monochrome bitmap?

mspaint.exe? I doubt that it has proper command line options to automate that.

in regards to your problem (and not the question) then I think you should try to make a pdf instead (E.g. using ITextSharp). And then try that with colors and all. Or just try to convert it to pdf yourself (with color) and see if that prints.

@Ralf I hope so too, this is what I'm looking for

@ThomasKoelle Thanks for your comment, but this is a label printer, and if you want to print an image, it only supports monochrome bmps saved using the paint software that comes with windows, and any code I have tried so far that will convert monochrome bmps cannot meet its requirements.

There are many ways to do color conversions. If you only need to handle a specific source and target format, and are fine with unsafe code, it is not that difficult to do yourself:
        public static unsafe Bitmap Bgr24ToGrayscale8(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            if (bmp.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb) 
                throw new InvalidOperationException("invalid pixelformat");
            var bytesPerPixel = 3;

            var sourceData = bmp.LockBits(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                bmp.PixelFormat);

            var height = bmp.Height;
            var width = bmp.Width;

            var result = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
            var resultData = result.LockBits(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                result.PixelFormat);
            
            try
            {
                var sourceStride = sourceData.Stride;
                var targetStride = resultData.Stride;
                var targetPtr = (byte*)resultData.Scan0;
                var sourcePtr = (byte*)sourceData.Scan0;
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    {
                        // Do the actual conversion
                        var i = y * sourceStride + x * bytesPerPixel;
                        var value = (byte)(sourcePtr[i + 0] * 0.11f + sourcePtr[i + 1] * 0.59f + sourcePtr[i + 2] * 0.3f);
                        targetPtr[y * targetStride + x] = value;
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                bmp.UnlockBits(sourceData);
                result.UnlockBits(resultData);
            }
            return result;
        }

While this looks like a lot of code, most of it is boiler plate to get access to the pointers for the pixel data. The inner loop simply takes each color pixel, compute the equivalent grayscale value. The constants are meant to compensate for the different sensitivity the eye has for different colors.
If you need more complicated conversions you might want to take a look at some image processing library, like Magic.Net.

Thanks for your help, but I tried your code and couldn't successfully print it. The strange thing is that this printer only supports monochrome bmp saved as using the drawing software that comes with Windows.

@Nodedefender note that this converts the image to monochrome, i.e. grayscale, as specified. It is possible that your printer requires a binary image. I.e. 1bit per pixel. That would require some thresholding, as well as packing multiple pixels in a single byte, for that it might be easier to use a third party library.

This Answer from the give information will fix your problem. I think the problem seem to be that the bitmap is not Format1bppIndexed pixel format. The provided link convert any pixel format bitmap to a Format1bppIndexed bitmap.
